# Spark Json schema return datatype as String for every columns

Tags: json, apache-spark, optimization, schema, apache-spark-sql

On reading json data df schema returns all columns as string, if I explicitly change datatypes to corresponding one will it increase performance or benefit me in some way?

Comment: default is String Types. explicitly changing dataTypes won't effect unless you have two data types in same column. Benefit really depends on what your requirements are for further processing. If further processings are suitable for stringTypes, let them be Strings else change them.

Comment: Yes, but spark internally converts them to suitable datatypes when we perform aggregate like min max. So, is it advisable to convert dataframe we got from json to rdd and then pass schema with correct datatypes to get corresponding DF?

Comment: Thats advisable as I already said in my first comment :)